# Все возможные суммы всех длин элементов двумерного массива

Tags: python, рекурсия

Мне нужно получить список всех возможных сумм всех элементов двумерного массива

Для примера возьмем массив

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 9], [7, 14]]
```

Тогда список сумм должен быть таким

```
1+3,1+6,1+9,2+3,2+6,2+9,3+3,3+6,3+9,1+7,1+14,2+7,2+14,3+7,3+14,3+7,3+14,6+7,6+14,9+7,9+14,1+3+7,1+3+14,1+6+7,1+6+14,1+9+7,1+9+14,2+3+7,2+3+14,2+6+7,2+6+14,2+9+7,2+9+14,3+3+7,3+3+14,3+6+7,3+6+14,3+9+7,3+9+14
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону itertools https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 3):

Перебираем комбинации списков. Перебираем сочетания элементов из комбинаций списков:

```
import itertools


def sums(lst):
    for l in range(2, len(lst) + 1):
        for c in itertools.combinations(lst, l):
            yield from itertools.product(*c)


for s in sums([[1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 9], [7, 14]]):
    print(' + '.join(map(str, s)), '=', sum(s))
```

> ```
> $ python sums.py
> 1 + 3 = 4
> 1 + 6 = 7
> 1 + 9 = 10
> 2 + 3 = 5
> 2 + 6 = 8
> 2 + 9 = 11
> 3 + 3 = 6
> 3 + 6 = 9
> 3 + 9 = 12
> 1 + 7 = 8
> 1 + 14 = 15
> 2 + 7 = 9
> 2 + 14 = 16
> 3 + 7 = 10
> 3 + 14 = 17
> 3 + 7 = 10
> 3 + 14 = 17
> 6 + 7 = 13
> 6 + 14 = 20
> 9 + 7 = 16
> 9 + 14 = 23
> 1 + 3 + 7 = 11
> 1 + 3 + 14 = 18
> 1 + 6 + 7 = 14
> 1 + 6 + 14 = 21
> 1 + 9 + 7 = 17
> 1 + 9 + 14 = 24
> 2 + 3 + 7 = 12
> 2 + 3 + 14 = 19
> 2 + 6 + 7 = 15
> 2 + 6 + 14 = 22
> 2 + 9 + 7 = 18
> 2 + 9 + 14 = 25
> 3 + 3 + 7 = 13
> 3 + 3 + 14 = 20
> 3 + 6 + 7 = 16
> 3 + 6 + 14 = 23
> 3 + 9 + 7 = 19
> 3 + 9 + 14 = 26
> ```